# If an approach chart says "GPS required", do I need GNSS capability to fly it?

Tags: approach, aeronautical-charts

If an aircraft is /Y, /C, or /I (RNAV no GNSS), can they fly an approach chart that says "DME/DME/IRU or GPS required"? GPS in my mind is a GNSS. If you don't have DME/DME/IRU and are RNAV (non-GNSS) capable, can you legally fly the approach?

An example of a chart that has the "DME/DME/IRU or GPS required" notation is [here](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1811/00322GEELA.PDF).

Answer (score 2):

> If you don't have DME/DME/IRU and are RNAV (non-GNSS) capable, can you legally fly the approach?

**The chart the OP refers to is shown below.**

1. As you can see from the STAR (standard terminal arrival), which is not an "approach" you have to have either "GPS" or a "DME/DME/IRU" capable RNAV system. Older RNAV systems that do not have an IRU (inertial reference system) would not qualify for this STAR.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Follow-on question: If an aircraft is /Y, /C, or /I (RNAV no GNSS), does it automatically mean that they have a DME/DME/IRU system?

Comment: @jeff0000- /Y/C/I means RNAV.  "RNAV" system does not automatically mean that it (RNAV system) includes an IRU.  VOR/DME, DME/DME systems can be RNAV systems.  Good info in AC 20-130, AC 20-138, and AC 90-108.